# DOSBOX How do I convert MASM code to NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm, dosbox

I'm trying to write code that will print a 5 by 5 grid of asterisks but I'm forced to use DOS. The first part of my assignment is to assemble the code in MASM and the second part is to translate the MASM code to NASM. Can anyone help me translate the MASM code to NASM?.

MASM code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
  Asterisks DB '*****',0DH,0AH,'$'

.code
  Main Proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 5

    _loop1:
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, Asterisks
    int 21H
    dec cx
    jnz _loop1

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
  Main ENDP
END Main
```

Comment: Please formulate a more specific question than _"can someone help me with this?"_. What exactly are you having trouble with? Have you consulted the manuals for the respective assemblers?

Answer (score 1):

I saved your MASM code to the file "sonicM.asm",
assembled with Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.11c
`ml.exe /c sonicM.asm`
or with Borland Turbo Assembler Version 4.0
`tasm.exe sonicM.asm`
linked with  Borland Turbo Link Version 3.01
`tlink.exe sonicM.obj`
and executed with DOSBox version 0.74-2
`sonicM.exe`

Most differences between assemblers manifests in their pseudoinstructions and directives.
You can study NASM directives at https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc0.html
The following source was saved as "sonicN.asm"

```
; Assembled with NASM version 2.15.05
; nasm.exe -f obj sonicN.asm
; linked with Borland Turbo Link Version 3.01
; tlink.exe sonicM.obj
; and executed with DOSBox version 0.74-2
; sonicN.exe

; .model small                       ; NASM doesn't support memory models.
SEGMENT .stack                       ; NASM defines segments with pseudoinstruction SEGMENT 
        resb 100h                    ;  or with pseudoinstruction SECTION, which is the same.
    
SEGMENT .data
  Asterisks DB '*****',0DH,0AH,'$'

SEGMENT .code
  Main: ; Proc                      ; NASM doesn't support pseudoinstruction PROC.
    mov ax, data                    ; NASM doesn't prefix segment names with '.' or '@'.
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 5

    _loop1:
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, Asterisks               ; NASM tolerates the absence of brackets in LEA. 
    int 21H
    dec cx
    jnz _loop1

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
 ; Main ENDP                         ; NASM doesn't support pseudoinstruction ENDPROC.
; END Main                           ; NASM requires the entry point labeled ..start:
                                     ;     or to be at the start of code segment.
```

And this is how would your source (saved as "sonicE.asm") look in EuroAssembler,
assembled and linked with €ASM version 20191104
`euroasm.exe sonicE.asm`
and executed with DOSBox version 0.74-2
`sonicE.exe`

```
; .model small                       ; €ASM uses pseudoinstruction PROGRAM to specify format, model, entry.
sonicE PROGRAM Format=MZ, Model=small, Entry=Main:

[.stack] SEGMENT                     ; €ASM requires segment name in the label field in brackets.
    DB 100h*BYTE

[.data] SEGMENT                      ; €ASM requires segment name in the label field in brackets.
  Asterisks DB '*****',0DH,0AH,'$'

[.code] SEGMENT                      ; €ASM requires segment name in the label field in brackets.
  Main: Proc
    mov ax, PARA# [.data]            ; Paragraph address of the segment bottom is available as PARA# [segment]
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, 5

    _loop1:
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, [Asterisks]             ; €ASM requires references to memory variables in square brackets.
    int 21H
    dec cx
    jnz _loop1

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
;  Main ENDP                        ; ENDblocks in €ASM may have their name in the operand field.
   ENDP Main
; END Main                          ; PROGRAM in €ASM requires the corresponding ENDPROGRAM.
  ENDPROGRAM sonicE
```